# Facebook Open Graph test user has different Story layout

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Firstly, the images to accompany the following descriptions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl5nE.jpg

I have created a custom Open Graph story for my app. The story is called **Record a Race**. I modified the story to include some parameters (name and results) that I added to my **race** object **(see image 1)**. Pretty simple stuff.

When my app launches the Facebook share dialog while *my account* is logged in to the Facebook app on my phone, the share dialog mirrors the story layout I set up **(see image 2)**. All good so far.

However, when my app launches the FB share dialog while a *test user account* is logged in to the FB app, the share dialog looks like the regular dialog, not including my modifications to the story **(see image 3)**.

Has anyone come across this? I can't find anything on Stack Overflow or the Facebook Developers documentation.

*Thanks!*